# The action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{H}$ is proper

Tags: group-actions, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}:=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\Im (z)>0\}$ with the hyperbolic metric, and the group $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})=SL_2(\mathbb{R})/\{\pm I_2\}$, where $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $2\times 2$ real matrices with determinant equal to $1$, which acts on $\mathbb{H}$ by Möbius transformations. I'd like to show that this action is proper, i.e.

> For any compact set $P\subset \mathbb{H}$ there exists a compact set $L\subset PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $z,g(z)\in P$ for some $g\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ implies $g\in L$.

My reasoning was that, if such an $L$ where to exists, then surely

$$ \bigcup_{z\in P} \{g\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R}): g(z)\in P\}\subset L$$

and thus the closure of the LHS would be compact. Hence, a first candidate for $L$ would be

$$L:=\text{cl}\left( \bigcup_{z\in P} \{g\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R}): g(z)\in P\}\right ).$$

I'm stuck in showing that this is indeed compact. I tried to show sequential compactness, taking $g_n\in L$, which gives $z_n\in P$ such that $g_n(z_n)\in P$ from which we can extract a subsequences $z_{n_k}$ and a $z\in P$ such that $z_{n_k}\to z$, but I don't see how to fabricate a $g$ to act as a cluster point for the original sequences. Any hints? For reference, this is a problem in  *Ergodic theory with a view towards number theory* by M. Ensiedler and T. Ward.

Comment: It should be enough to show $\{ g \in PSL_2(\mathbb{R}), |g(i)-i| \le \epsilon\}$ is compact, where $g(i) = \frac{i+(ac+bd)}{c^2+d^2}$

Comment: @reuns Woops, didn't see the edit. Thank you for your comment, but I'm not sure I see why that suffices. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Take $u,v \in PSL_2$ such that $u(i) = z,v(i)=s$ then $|g(z)-s| > \epsilon \implies |v^{-1}gu(i)-i| > C \epsilon$

Comment: This implies your $L$ is bounded (and it is clearly closed). Looking at $|g(i)-i|$ is not hard, letting $f = \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \in [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$ we get $|(\frac{ci+d}{f}) \cdot (fai+fb)|  \le \epsilon, | (\frac{ci+d}{if}) \cdot (fai+fb)| = 1$ where $\cdot $ is the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this implies $f^2a^2+f^2b^2 \le 1+\epsilon$ and that the set is bounded.

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry, but why can you take $f\in [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$. Isn't the boundedness of $c$ and $d$ part of what we're trying to prove?

Comment: It is a consequence of say $|g(i)-i| \le \epsilon/2$. And choosing $u_k,v_k$ correctly you can divide $L$ in (finitely many) pieces where $|v_k^{-1}  g u_k(i)-i| \le \epsilon/2$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry to bother you again. I can see that if we take a cover $P\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n D_\varepsilon(z_k)$, then it suffices to see that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{z\in D_\varepsilon(z_j)}\{g\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R}): |g(z)-z|\le \varepsilon\}$ is bounded for all $j$ and $k$, and I'm guessing that in order to see this we would take Möbius maps which send $i$ to $z_l$, for each $l$, but couldn't this disrupt the inequalities (we're aiming to get $|h(i)-i|\le C\varepsilon$ for some $h$ obtained from $g$ by composition with the $h_l$, right?)

Comment: It is enough to show $B_\epsilon(z,s)= \{ g \in PSL_2, |g(z)- s| \le \epsilon\}$ is bounded and find $A= \bigcup_{k=1}^n B_{\varepsilon_k}(z_k,s_k)$ such that $L \subset A$ to obtain that $L$ is bounded, and since it is clearly closed, we get $L$ is compact. Finally $B_\epsilon(z,s)$ is bounded (for $s,z \in H$ and $\epsilon$ small enough) because $B_\epsilon(i,i)$ is bounded.

Comment: @reuns It seems reasonable, but I haven't been able to find $s_j$ such that $\bigcup_{z\in P}\{g\in PSL_2: |g(z)-z_k|\le \varepsilon\}\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^m \{g\in PSL_2: |g(s_j)-z_k|\le varepsilon\}$, where $z_k$ is fixed.

Comment: Don't comment again, I won't reply.

Comment: @reuns Sorry for being so annoying, I tremendously appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

- Given $z_0$ and $P$.

  Find finitely many balls $B_\epsilon(\tau_k)=\{\tau,|\tau-\tau_k|\le\epsilon_k\}$ such that $P \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^K B_\epsilon(\tau_k)$

  take $u,v_k \in PSL_2$ such that $u(z_0) = i$, $v_k(i) = \tau_k$

  thus $$Lu^{-1} = \{ gu^{-1} \in PSL_2, g(z_0) \in P\}=\{ g \in PSL_2, g(i) \in P\} \\ \subset\quad \bigcup_{k=1}^K \{  g \in PSL_2, |g(i)-v_k(i)| \le \epsilon_k\}$$
- Since $g(i) = \frac{i+(ac+bd)}{c^2+d^2}$ and $ad-bc=1$ you'll find that $|g(i)-i| \le \epsilon$ implies $f = \sqrt{c^2+d^2} \in (1-2\epsilon,1+2\epsilon)$ and $|(\frac{ci+d}{f}) \cdot (fai+fb)|  \le \epsilon, | (\frac{ci+d}{if}) \cdot (fai+fb)| = 1$ which implies $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \in (1-4\epsilon ,1+4\epsilon)$.

  (where $\cdot$ is the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$)
- Thus $\{  g \in PSL_2, |g(i)-i| \le \epsilon\}$ is bounded, as well as $\{  g \in PSL_2, |g(i)-v_k(i)| \le \epsilon_k\}$ and $Lu^{-1}$ and $L$. And since $L$ is clearly closed it means it is compact.

Of course all this works iff we stay carefully in some compact included in the upper half-plane. If $P \cap \mathbb{R} \ne \emptyset$ it doesn't work. The same holds for the balls $\{  g \in PSL_2, |g(i)-i| \le \epsilon\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another definition of a map $f$ being proper: the preimage of every compact set is compact.

The group you describe, $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$, is the group of isometries of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$. To see this, first we note that it's the group of biholomorphic maps from $\mathbb H^2$ to itself (see the [groupprops wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(2,R))), and that in a space of constant, non-zero Gaussian curvature, any map that preserves angles will also preserve area.

Isometries and their inverses map compact sets to compact sets, and so it follows that the group of actions you describe are proper.